# Broken dependencies after installing netatalk

Tags: apt, dependencies

Recently I've installed netatalk from sources on my home server. Few days ago I've tried to install some packages using apt-get but I've got a message about broken dependencies.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 krb5-multidev : Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.3) but 1.10.1+dfsg-2 is to be installed
             Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (= 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.3) but 1.10.1+dfsg-2 is to be installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu15 is to be installed
            Recommends: manpages-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.13-20ubuntu5.1) but 2.15-0ubuntu15 is to be installed
 libnih1 : Depends: libc6 (< 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu15 is to be installed
 ushare:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libdlna0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libupnp3:i386 (>= 1.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

sudo apt-get -f install wants to completely remove all packages I've got installed on my system. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

First, you do what it told you to do:

> ```
> Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
> ```

(This message is from Debian; you should actually run `sudo apt-get -f install`.)

If this doesn't correct the problem, then do all of the following:

1. Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and make sure you are on a single version (e.g. `precise`) and haven't tried to mix in sources from e.g. quantal, etc.
2. Disable any third party PPAs you may be using.
3. Run `sudo apt-get clean`.
4. Run `sudo apt-get update`.
5. Run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.